# Cant add record to sqlite database using DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, android-dialogfragment

im trying to add records to my sqlite database. If you click "add" a DialogFragment opens. Then when you write some information into the textfield and pick one option in the Spinner it should be added to the sqlite databse. This works if i do it from the main activity. But i only get FC when im trying to fo the same from the DialogFragment.

DialogFragment code:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Spinner spin;
    EditText etNumber, etForwardNumber;
    Boolean initialDisplay = true;
    Database mDB = new Database(getActivity());
    Cursor c;

public void DialogFragment(){
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);

    etNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
    etForwardNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etForwardNumber);

    etNumber.setHint("Phone Number");
    etForwardNumber.setHint("Forward Number");

    etForwardNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spOptions);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Block Call");
    list.add("Forward Call");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); 
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("DIALOGFRAGMENT", "Option selected: " + position);
            if (position == 0) {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Block");
                etForwardNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Log.d("LOG_TAG", initialDisplay.toString());
                //initialDisplay = false;
            }else {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Forward");
                etForwardNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

    builder.setMessage("")
        .setTitle("Add a new number")
        .setView(view);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Hide the dialog
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //Add records to sqlite database
            mDB.open();
            String cname = "test";
            String caction = "Forward";
            //String cnumber = "Numbertoforward";
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("cName", cname);
            cv.put("cAction", caction);
            //cv.put("cNumber", cnumber);
            mDB.empInsert(cv);
            c.requery();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}

/*@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate the XML view for the help dialog fragment
    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, container);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    /*builder.setMessage("Test msg")
        .setTitle("Title");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });*/
    /*return view;
    } */
}
```

Logcat:

```
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at com.spxc.forwardcalls.Database.open(Database.java:23)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at com.spxc.forwardcalls.CustomDialogFragment$3.onClick(CustomDialogFragment.java:90)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:112)
10-23 15:06:00.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14935):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say at the get go, but it seems your database is not initialised properly. You should move

```
Database mDB = new Database(getActivity());
```

to your onCreateDialog method. Moving it here would ensure that getActivity() returns a context to initialise the database with.

Alternatively, I highly recommend having a DatabaseHelper class of some sort that uses a singleton pattern. Therefore, you could access your database from anywhere in your app more flexibly.

Comment: Still get FC, but the data is added :)

Comment: [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery())